# Have you seen this unfamiliar theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

There are two theorems that mentioned in my solution manual book and i'm not familiar with this.

> Theorem 1 :
>
> Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a simply-connected region $R$, then
> $\displaystyle\int_a^z f(\zeta) \mathbb d\zeta$ is independent of the
> path in $R$ joining a complex number $a$ and arbitrary complex numbers
> $z$ are any two points in $R$
>
> Theorem 2 :
>
> Suppose $a$ and $z$ are any two points in $R$ and
> $G(z)=\displaystyle\int_a^z f(\zeta) \mathbb d\zeta$. Then $G(z)$ is
> analytic in $R$ and $G'(z)=f(\zeta)$

Do those theorems really exist? Bcz i've never seen before.

My solution book, used this to show that the function is independent. But it's weird to me. Because what i've learned in vector calculus, the path independence is some kind of

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

Or the line integral is zero.

Is my solution book is false? If they are really exist, what is their motivation? could i use the fact in that theorem, If the derivative of a function ($G'(z)$) is equal to the function $f(\zeta)$ then $\displaystyle\int_a^z f(\zeta) \mathbb d\zeta$ is independent of the path in $R$, no matter what the point ($z$) is?

If it's not clear, please comment i'll edit. Thanks

EDIT :

My question on my book (it's just an information not a question, my main question is written above)

Show that $\int_{\pi-\pi i}^{z} \cos 3\zeta\mathbb d\zeta$ is independent of the path C

Comment: Isn't theorem 2 a complex analog of the fundamental theorem of calculus part 1?

Comment: Isn't there some extra hypothesis needed in theorem 2?

Comment: Yes. But in my solution that theorem is used to show that the function is independent.

Comment: @kimchilover i'm not sure. It's just mentioned in my solution book

Comment: Theorem 2 looks like [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do those theorems really exist?
>   Is my solution book is false?
>   Could i use the fact in that theorem?

Yes, no, yes.

The fact that $G$ is holomorphic is indeed Morera's theorem.

Below i give a quick sketch of the third yes
(in the language of differential forms).

If you don't know differential forms then i recommend to look up
the section "integration along paths" in **any** complex analysis book,
for instance Robert B. Ash 
[Complex variables](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/CV.html).

You are going to see few lemmas whose proofs are essentially the same
of the ones you already know (proving the same thing twice can only
reinforce its understanding).
But overall the proofs in complex analysis books are more elementary
and appropriate for a first encounter.

Below it is shown how to use differential forms
(and the results you mention) to the situation in case.
In particular it should clarify what theorem 1 and 2 says.

---

Let $\alpha \in \Omega^1(U)$ be a 1-form over an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (here considered real valued,
but it works verbatim for complex values). The following are equivalent:

1. the form $\alpha$ is exact, ie.
   $$\sum_i \alpha_i \, \mathrm{d} x_i = \alpha = \mathrm{d} F
        = \sum_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} \, \mathrm{d} x_i$$
   for some smooth function $F \in C^{\infty}(U)$;
2. the integral
   $$\int_{\gamma} \alpha$$
   depends only on the endpoints of the smooth curve $\gamma$;
3. the equality
   $$ \int_{\gamma} \alpha = 0$$
   holds for any closed curve $\gamma$.

In particular condition (2) allows one to define the integral of a $1$-forms
along continuous curve
$$\gamma \colon [0, 1] = I \to U.$$
by considering any polygonal map $\tilde{\gamma}$ from $\gamma(0)$
to $\gamma(1)$ and defining
$$ \int_{\gamma} \alpha = \int_{\tilde{\gamma}} \alpha.$$

The function $f$ in 1 is called *primitive* of $\alpha$; the equivalence (2) $\Leftrightarrow$ (3) is easy.

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2): by the `fundamental theorem of calculus' (and
  commutativity of differential and pullback)
$$
\int_{\gamma} \mathrm{d} F
= \int_I \gamma^{\ast}(\mathrm{d} F)
= \int_I \mathrm{d} (F \circ \gamma) = F(\gamma(1)) - F(\gamma(0)).
$$

The only nontrivial statement is (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1).
Fix a point $p \in U$ and for any $x \in U$ define
$$
F(x) = \int_{\gamma} \alpha
$$
where $\gamma$ is any (piecewise) smooth curve from $p$ to $x$.
By hypotesis the integral is well defined, ie. do not depend on the path.
Then $F$ is a primitive for $\alpha$
(you have to compute the partial derivatives).

---

What you recall from calculus is that if $U$ is simply connected then
any closed form (your condition on partial derivatives) is exact,
which is known as Poincaré lemma.

Now, you can study *holomorphic functions* as complex differentiable functions or as (real) differentiable functions on $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying Cauchy-Riemann equation:
$$0 = \overline{\partial} f = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x - i \partial_y) f.$$
This is also known as delta-bar equation, where
$$
\partial = \partial_z = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_x + i \partial y) \qquad
\overline{\partial} = \partial_{\overline{z}}
= \frac{1}{2} (\partial_x - i \partial y)
$$
are the so called *Wirtinger derivatives*.

Assuming $f = u + iv$ the delta-bar equation rewrites as
$$
0
= \overline{\partial} f
= \frac{1}{2} (\partial_x u - \partial_y v)
  + \frac{1}{2} \, i \, (\partial_x v + \partial_y u)
$$
and equating real and immaginary part to zero you read the usual
Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Then
$$
\mathrm{d} (f \, \mathrm{d} z)
= \mathrm{d} f \wedge \mathrm{d} z
= (\partial f \, \mathrm{d} z
   + \overline{\partial} f \, \mathrm{d} \overline{z}) \wedge \mathrm{d} z
= 0
$$
where the first addendum is zero since $\mathrm{d} z \wedge \mathrm{d} z = 0$
and the second one is zero by delta-bar equation.

Therefore (surprise) the 1-form $\alpha = f \, \mathrm{d} z$ is closed,
and over a simply connected domain $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ there is a smooth function $g$ such that
$$
f \, \mathrm{d} z = \mathrm{d} g
= \partial g \, \mathrm{d} z + \overline{\partial} g \, \mathrm{d} \overline{z}
$$
ie. $g$ holomorphic and such that $f = g'$.

Again, if you don't want to work with complex valued differential forms,
you can decompose into real and immaginary parts and work real valued ones.